# Tracking row numbers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way I could keep track of modified tables in Oracle?

Is there a master table that keeps track of all other table's row? For example if I add a row to table1 it would update the row count stating that table1 now has 5 rows.

I was thinking of tracking either `dba_tables` or `all_tables` or `user_tables` but I'm not sure which one actually counts the number of rows each table has.

Comment: Oracle 3 was released *30 years* ago, and superseded by v4 a year later...

Comment: @Paolo please correct with the Oracle version you have, not the Oracle SQL Developer version (which I guess the 3.1 refers to.)

Comment: @ypercube. Good catch, that was the oracle sql developer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS
FROM USER_TABLES
```

I highly doubt you're actually using Oracle 3.1. This query works at least in 11g (I don't have other instances to test at the moment).

Keep in mind that this is a data dictionary table and it won't update automatically after you insert a row in any schema table. The Gather Statistics procedure must be run to update these records.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an improvement on the just querying user/all/dba_statistics by combining them with information gathered by table monitoring.

The views DBA/ALL/USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS are populated with the number on insets, updates, deletes and truncates on the table since statistics were last gathered. The view is populated asynchronously so call DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO to flush the latest in-memory data to the tables.

Bear in mind that statistics themselves may be estimated, and although the accuracy is pretty good on most tables even to surprisingly low levels of estimation percent (even down to 5% or below), if you need accurate numbers you'll have to query the tables themselves with count(*). You can put together a pipelined function to do this for multiple tables with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

1. The only difference among `dba|user|all_tables` is scope. `user_tables` limit the output to the tables you own, `all_tables` is basically `user_tables` + tables from other schemas you've been granted access to, and `dba_tables` is everything that exists in the database.
2. `num_rows` is a valid option to track amount of number of rows in a table. unfortunately, it is not calculated real-time, but as a part of table statistics collection operation. There is no out of the box option of tracking amount of rows in real-time I am aware of.